# Swift - Segmented Control is hidden without being on nav bar

Tags: swift, xcode

I followed [this great tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/) and got everything working, but the issue is, the segmented button only shows up if it is on the navigation bar. If I move it anywhere else, it disappears.

I'v tried many experiments and fiddling but no results. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to look for the segmented control in the View UI Hierarchy from Xcode's Debug Navigator?

Comment: what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

Run your app in your simulator and navigate to the area of the app that you would like to inspect. Then, from Xcode's Xcode's Debug Navigator, select View UI Hierarchy. [image]

And then, you should be able to inspect the view. I often find that the component is mistakenly hidden by another or not at all in the view which means it may hidden, or not properly added. [image]

Comment: So in other words move the segmented control into a position where it's always going to show in the view regardless if the view was switched or not?.

Comment: In other words, I can move the segmented control to a hierarchy that always displays in the frame regardless if the view was switched or not. EDIT: Seems like that can't be done.... or can it?